# How to fix Lysol damage to furniture?

Tags: furniture

I was cleaning my wooden bed with Lysol and afterwards noticed weird grey marks. Now I can't remove them.

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Woodworking SE. This looks like standard clouding, caused by water getting trapped in/under the finish. It may or may not be reversible. If it has been a couple of days and there has been no change (pale stains from water can go away on their own) you can try heating the area with a hairdryer and see if it has any effect. More than likely it will only give minimal improvement, but it will tell you it is a water mark rather than a bleaching effect from the Lysol.

Comment: Help I sprayed lysol on an old wood table and now I have white spots I can't remove. Please let me know what I can try Thank you

Comment: @Ses Welcome to Woodworking.SE! Please note you will need to accumulate rep by asking or answering questions before you can post comments on your own. You did a good job finding an existing question, but as this one has no answers, feel free to post a new one of your own with more details, a picture, and what you have tried so far. You can also reference this question to help us link the duplicate questions.

Comment: And @Ses, in order to give better responses we'll need more details than this! Post a pic or, ideally, a couple of pics of the problem — "white spots" can be a number of different things.

Comment: I can confirm that alcohol dampened cloth done gently worked great on my mahogany desk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove a watermark?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/how-do-i-remove-a-watermark)

Answer (score 1):

This is clouding from from water vapors in the Lysol getting trapped in under the finish.  Sometimes you can take a very lightly alchohol dampened cloth and gently, very gently wipe over the area.  Don’t press into the wood and don’t stay in one spot too long. You can also try a heat source like a hair dryer.